# Aggregating Mongodb array values using $unwind takes forever

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo, aggregation

I have a big collection (>100M documents) and of its fields is an array that may contain up to ~500 values.
I'm trying to count how many times each unique value repeats itself in the collection.

The thing is that it takes hours to complete.

The array field is indexed.

As an example (to further explain what I'm trying to achieve), let's say we have the following documents

```
doc_1 = {'name': 'George', 'books': ['123', '321']}
doc_2 = {'name': 'Julia', 'books': ['555', '321']}
```

And I want to get the following

```
{'123': 1, '321': 2, '555': 1}
```

What I'm currently doing is

```
query = [
    {'$unwind': f"${books}"},
    {'$group': {"_id": f"${books}", "count": {'$sum': 1}}}
]
db_connection.collection_name.aggregate(query, allowDiskUse=True)
```

When I'm running this on the actual collection (again, >100M documents) with allowDiskUse=False I'm getting a memory issue, that's why I'm using it as True.

In addition, I tried using different batchSize but even though I read about it I don't fully understand how it works and whether it actually improves something.

I tried using Projection for the 'books' field but it didn't do any good.

I understand that using $unwind basically duplicates the documents (keeps _id) as the number of values in every document's array and it doesn't make sense to duplicate all the other fields, this is why using $projection made sense in my mind. But again, no change.

How can I optimize this query?

Comment: `$limit` Limit your records you process at once, do it in chunks

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar can you share a concrete example please? I don't understand what it means doing it in chunks. Isn't it what batchSize intents to do?

Comment: you're screwed due to the decision to embed books in the user documents. the unwind and group would work relatively fast if the dataset was not that big. but in your case, you'd be better off storing the relationship in a separate collection `UserBooks`. then you can add a sort stage before the group stage to utilize the index and mongo wouldn't need to examine any docs because the index already has that info and it would be a covered query. but still, not sure how much RAM an index would use for >100m * ~500 items. alternatively, compute the counts at the moment of adding books to users.